# What does three {{{ }}} in mustache.js mean?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I am looking at mustache.js based template and the person has defined some variables as 
`{{variable}}` and sometimes `{{{variable2}}}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [**documentation**](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: `{{{name}}}`